# fill array value from database

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following PHP array:

```
$config= array(
 "Plan" => array( "Type" => "dropdown", "Options" => "value1, value2, value3"),
);
```

Now, Instead of hardcoding these values(value1, value2 etc); I want these values(value1,value2 etc) to be fetched from a database.

```
$rs = mysql_query('SELECT value from tbloptions');
$optvalue = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

I have been thinking about this from past half hours but I can't figure out on How to proceed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_fetch_array return one row at a time, so you have to call the function until there are no more rows. For each row, grab the value and insert it into a numerically indexed array. The join function takes each value of that array, and concatenates them into a string, with the specified delimiter:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $opt[] = $row['value'];
}

$config['Options'] = implode(', ', $opt);
```

Comment: this exactly what I neded. Perfect!

Comment: but this array is not working as jquery autocomplete when i use json_encode, why?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to build an array of options and implode it...

```
foreach ($optvalue as $option)
{
    $options[] = $option['value']
}

$config['Options'] = implode(', ', $options);
```

Comment: Yes, I was not aware from of implode/explode functions. Very handy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT value from tbloptions');
$rows = "";
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
   $rows[] = $row;
}
mysql_free_result( $rows );
```